# How do you make the underscore active in environments but preserve its orignal use in math mode?

Tags: macros, symbols

I'm experimenting with creating a formatting shorthand package. I want to use the underscore to delimit an underlined text span, like so

```
some text _underlined text_ more text
```

Simply making the underscore active defining a macro

```
\catcode`_=\active%
\def_#1_{\underline{1}}%
```

is not viable since this obviously collides with the use of the underscore in math mode.

Is it possible to have both work? If so, how?

Comment: The answer to your question *title* is yes. The answer to your question body is move complicated. Could you re-word your title to match your document (something more specific)?

Comment: @Werner I changed the title to be more specific.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it, but it's better not to. Really, and not only because underlining is considered bad practice in typography. You gain nothing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\ustextormath{\ifmmode\expandafter_\else\expandafter\usunderline\fi}

\begingroup\lccode`~=`_
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \def\usunderline#1~{\underline{#1}}
  \protected\def~{\ustextormath}
}

\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\_=\active}

\begin{document}

\section{Some _underlined_ text and $a_1$}

some text _underlined text_ more text and $a_1$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "You gain nothing."?

Comment: @FK82 You clutter your text with strange characters that don't really show the logical markup.

Comment: Ok. Sure. You got a point.

Answer (score 5):

Good evening, please try this if it fits your needs. Technically, underscore is an active character from category 8 in my example during typesetting. I used `\sb` in the math mode and condition for closing `\it` (`\itshape`) in a group in the text mode. The `\mycondition` is returning to `false` automatically when leaving a group.

Thank you for useful comments and tips egreg, alexis and FK82! It was fun!

```
\catcode`\_=13% Or use \active; from category 8.
\def\false{false}\def\mycondition{false}%
\def_{\ifmmode\sb
  \else
    \ifx\mycondition\false
      \begingroup\def\mycondition{true}\it%\itshape for LaTeXists
        \else
      \endgroup
    \fi
  \fi}
Text _more of text_ ToDo $abc_i^2 math$ even more _text_ etc.
%\bye
```

**Bonus:** This is a one-liner with `\newif` involved:

```
\catcode`_=13\newif\ifmyif\myiffalse\def_{\ifmmode\sb\else\ifmyif\endgroup\else\begingroup\myiftrue\it\fi\fi}Text _more of text_ ToDo $abc_i^2 math$ even more _text_ etc.%\bye
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: The usual category code of `_` is 8, not 13.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you. :-) So, you're toggling `\mytemp` on every `_` to switch between `\upshape` and `\itshape`? Neat!

Comment: Oh yes, thank you, I meant in my example during typesetting.

Comment: Oh, and changing the category code of `^^J` is definitely not a good idea. Use `\sb` which is a perfect substitute for the usual `_` as a subscript prefix.

Comment: @FK82 Yes, that's it. If you change the second line to `\newcount\mytemp \mytemp=1\itshape` you are getting reverse in the text mode.

Comment: @egreg Yes, you are right, it needs some improvements, I wished to left something for others in this nice and cozy problem.

Comment: You should be using a conditional instead of a counter, but this is the least defect in your macro.

Comment: @Malipivo I just confirmed that your solution works without the first line and with `\ifmmode\sb` in the fourth as @egreg suggested.

Comment: Please feel free to post a bright new version, you know, I am just happy I solved it within minutes somehow (not days or not at all like some years ago).

Comment: @FK82 First: you can't use a command such as `\underline` (well, you should *never* underline text, but that's by way of example). Second, a command such as `\itshape` should always be used in a group, so the end of the group would reestablish the previous conditions without an explicit font change that might be wrong. Third: try the command in a section title and you'll see.

Comment: @Malipivo That's why I commented: I see you have some skills and I would like to help in improving them. Surely not for gratuitous criticism.

Comment: I am happily working on the improvements, I just didn't know the style of work/cooperation as I am new here...

Comment: Another improvement, for more elegant code: Increment `\mytemp` immediately _after_ `\begingroup`, and the `\endgroup` will restore it to the zero value automatically.

Comment: @alexis Thank you for this tip, yes it was there in one edit but I unnecessary set it to zero manually after `\endgroup`. Now I improved it to a version without counter.

Comment: But you still set it to `false` manually... Anyway, why don't you just use `\newif\emphasis`? Then you can say things like `\ifemphasis` and `\emphasistrue`.

Comment: I meant this: `\begingroup\def\mycondition{true}...\endgroup Now: \mycondition` will print `Now: false`, because the `\def` is local to the group.